# Filter/query using OR?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I don't understand whats wrong with this CQL - It just checks if a new users email or username would conflict with an already existing person:

```
select email,username from person where email=? or username=?
```

Am I supposed to break it up into two separate queries? It says:

```
line 1:33 missing EOF at 'or')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use separate queries and merge: there is no OR in CQL (yet).

Comment: I have no idea what that means (: I guess its something like "union" in SQL? Ill have a look.

Comment: I mean you have to do it client side.  Merge the results of `select email,username from person where email=?` with `select email,username from person where username=?`.  Or if you just need to check if either exist then you can just see if any of them return anything.  Be careful with concurrency and consistency though, another thread could insert after you do this check.